# "http_server_requests_seconds_max" value increasing gradually for "/actuator/prometheus" overtime

Tags: spring, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

**"http_server_requests_seconds_max"** value increasing gradually for **"/actuator/prometheus"** overtime to **more than 2 seconds** per hit. Executing the prometheus query gives the below chart :

```
http_server_requests_seconds_max{app="myapp",uri="/actuator/prometheus"}
```

[image]

We were not able to figure out what is the problem or what is going wrong, would like to **reduce the latency time**. Let us kow what needs to be done.
The application is deployed on the Kubernetes environment.